# Worried about resetting Git commits

Tags: git, github

So I messed up my code on my local but luckily I commit to Git daily.

I've gone to my Git repo, downloaded the last working version of my code (from .zip format) and now I want to replace my code on my local.

How do I continue `git push` without resetting the number of commits?
Do I do a `git pull` first?

Answer (score 1):

If you downloaded a zip you don't have any `.git` folder. You need to re-clone the project again and then place your changes on top of it.

do a second clone and use a diff tool like beyond compare to compare the 2 folders and copy changes form one folder to the second one and then commit those changes.

Comment: hi @CodeWizard. Appreciate the quick response! Im not familiar with recloning on Git. What steps do I take?

Comment: open a new folder (the old one will be backup) `cd <root folder>; git clone <url>` now you have a new repository with the source from the remote. compare the content and grab the desired content.

Answer (score 0):

To reset your checked-out branch to look exactly like branch `master` on remote `origin`, do:

```
git remote update
```

followed by:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

If you also want to get rid of any build-generated/manually-created files, use a flavor of [git clean](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) (please refer docs):

```
git clean -fdx
```

Comment: I followed your instructions verbatim; worked like a charm :) Thank you Nishant!

Answer (score 0):

I recreated the problem and I also found another solution to my problem that work:

After I downloaded my Git backup and unzipped it, in terminal I ran 
`git init` followed by 
`git remote add origin the-name-of-my-git-backup.git` 
before running `git pull the-name-of-my-git-backup.git`
After that, I was able to resume `git add`, `git commit` and finally `git push`.

Definitely an experience!

Answer (score 0):

I have found another way of backtracking to a point in my application that  was working before I mess up.

1. First, stash away any uncommitted changes otherwise Git will complain:

   `git stash`
2. Then, simply check out an older branch that you know has the correct, working code. It could be the master branch, or some other branch like contact_form, etc. (replace previous_branch_name below with whichever branch you want to switch to):

   `git checkout previous_branch_name`
3. Delete the branch with the broken code to keep things organized:

   `git branch -D broken_branch`
4. Then checkout a new branch, and name it whatever is relevant:

   `git checkout -b new_branch_name`

Now, you will be back to the point where the app was working before in a previous branch's state!